# Would this sort of method chaining be frowned upon in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Say I have this code:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.Bar();
```

Would it be considered bad practice to do this instead?

```
new Foo().Bar();
```

Comment: Short answer: "No", but obviously hang on to the variable `foo` if you're going to need it later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do/see that all the time. Its comes from my habit of refactoring large methods into classes. I end up just calling:

```
new ClassThatWasAMethod(initialization, variables, here).PerformAction();
```

There *is* something called the Law of Demeter, that says any more than what you've done there is too "chatty". i.e.:

```
new Foo().Bar().Baz(); // potentially more
```

But, a badly named "Law" doesn't make it so. That is to say - you won't go to jail for not following that guideline.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty common.

[Fluid interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). You sample new up object from nowhere - functions used strictly for side effects are generally not welcome as they are harder to reason about. Usually it used to either start with existing object and modify its properties:

```
getMyItem(itemId).Width(42).Height(33).Open();
```

or build some item:

```
var result = new Builder().Width(42).Height(44).Create();
```

Another example is LINQ - you chain many queries to get result - again you usually use result but may just use for side effect.

Start with something and use result

```
var filteredSquares = myArray.Select(x => x * x).Where(r => r < 1000);
```

Strictly side effects (ignore results):

```
Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(x => x * x).Aggregate(0, (c,x)=> 
    {
       Console.Write(x); // side effect
       return 0; // to make Aggregate happy
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I find that a good practice.

One of the refactoring techniques is to remove the intermediate variable when used only once as long as the intention is obvious.

Introduce a variable only when the expression becomes complicated. The variable helps the code become self documenting.

```
IPizza hawaiianPizza = new PizzaBuilder()
    .AddCheese()
    .AddMushroom()
    .AddPineapples();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not passing any state to the constructor, then the method could most likely be made static and then the call would probably not raise any eyebrows.